# Help me find a hadith

Tags: hadith

I remember a hadith the prophet forbade man hitting their wife

and then the verse 34 of surah 4 came and the Prophet said something like

we wanted something by our heart but Allah wanted for us another thing
allah knows best

can you link me this hadith

Answer (score 2):

The narration is that a man slapped his wife, on which the prophet initially ruled that she will take qisas, however this verse was revealed and the prophet said: أردت أمرا وأراد الله غيره

It has been passed as a mursal report from Hasan al-Basri, recorded by [Tabari](https://al-maktaba.org/book/7798/11143), [Ibn Abi Hatim](https://al-maktaba.org/book/8658/931), [Ibn Abi Shaybah](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/31079) etc.  And as a report from Ali ibn Abi Talib, recorded by [Ibn Kathir](https://al-maktaba.org/book/23604/835) from Ibn Marduwayh.

Comment: Dear sister, since this Hadith is Mursal, what is the status of this narration, is this authentic or not? Please reply. Thanks.

Comment: @Ren I have not investigated the chains and do not know whether it is authentic, as the question did not ask for that. As  far as mursal is considered it is considered a type of weak hadith by many of the scholars of hadith, however it is also accepted by others when certain conditions are met.

Comment: Thanks you A LOT Umh you know so much in islam I often see your replies here

Comment: Thanks you A LOT Umh you know so much in islam I often see your replies here can I need to ask you another rare hadith that I am 100% sure it s exist it s not in a classic book of hadith  
on what I remember it s weak  hadith on a the travel of Dhu al-Qarnayn who reached somewhere that the sun doesnt reach and the sahaba asked how they see and the prophet replied there will be light coming of the earth he encounter 2 different people ( there wasnt human as far as I remember) and those species where bullied by Yajuj and Majuj
I am 100% sure this  hadith exist  I have seen in many times

Comment: I finally founded the hadith : it s talking about djaboulqa and djaboulsa from Tabari and the mountain QAF